# SignalR connection with accessTokenFactory on JS client doesn't connect with connectionId and UserIdentifier but .Net client is fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, signalr

In my SignalR Authentication prototype, the JS client doesn't have a Context.UserIdentifier and the connectionId will be 0 when connecting to the SignalR hub on the JS client side. It works fine with the .NET client.

Wondering if constructing the connection is wrong?
This is my connection:

```
state.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl("/chatHub", {
                    accessTokenFactory: async () => {
                        axios.post('https://localhost:44384/api/account/token', { email: email, password: password })
                            .then(async (response) => {
                                if (typeof response === 'undefined') {
                                    return;
                                }
                                else {
                                    console.log(response.data);
                                    console.log(state.connection.id);
                                    return response.data;
                                }
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

The WPF client connects with the token just fine with this code:

```
_connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44384/ChatHub", options =>
            {
                options.AccessTokenProvider = async () =>
                {
                    var tokenUserCommand = new TokenUserCommand
                    {
                        Email = emailTextBox.Text,
                        Password = passwordBox.Password
                    };

                    var token = await RestService.PostAsync<string>("account/token", tokenUserCommand);
                    return token;
                };

            })
            .Build();
```

Where I found [SignalR Authentication configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
and [SignalR Bearer Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=dotnet#configure-bearer-authentication)

Here is the [source for my prototype project](https://github.com/DanielRBowen/AuthnAuthzSignalR)

Answer (score 8):

The JS client requesting the token just needed an **await** keyword before axios.post. Such a rookie mistake which took more time than it should have.

```
state.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("https://localhost:44384/ChatHub", {
                accessTokenFactory: async () => {
                    if (state.accessToken === null) {
                        await axios.post('https://localhost:44384/api/account/token', { email: email, password: password })
                            .then(async (response) => {
                                if (typeof response === 'undefined') {
                                    return;
                                }
                                else {
                                    state.accessToken = response.data;
                                }
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    }
                    return state.accessToken;
                }
            })
            .build();
```